# QPlainTextEdit - how many lines can it contain?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qplaintextedit

Is it possible to calculate somehow the number of lines that will fit into a QPlainTextEdit control (with a certain size) before it overflows and shows a vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about getting the height and width of the box and then calculating it. You could (by hand) try to find some reasonable numbers for that - depending on the font format.